# how to stop displaying hidden field in source page of of running jsp

Tags: jsp

JSP page contains hidden field, in the web browser if i am checking the view source of that particular page then it is displaying hidden field.

i want this hidden field should not display in source page "View Sorce Page".

Answer (score 0):

Then don't code it in. As simple as that.

Another option is to store the value as an attribute in session or request.